# Facebook PHP SDK - Use SDK in a simple Website to retrieve public PAGE data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i am currently developing a small website for the bar my girlfriend works at. it is just a simple modern one page design. my girlfriend is also the administrator ob the bar's facebook page. now, i want to access the facebook pages info (like opening hours, next events... not very much, which is also public) to display it on the website. i was planing to pull this data once every 30 minutes to prevent api flooding. so i logged in as my girlfriend on facebook (this is personally my first encounter with facebook api/app development, so i don't know if this is correct), created a developer profile and an app.

now, i only find ways to get the correct access_token for the page using the '/me/accounts' etc methods and i can play with the graph api explorer and get the pages events and stuff and everything looks fine, except that i cannot retrieve this data through my long live app id/secret or app access_token.

So, how does this work? i think the facebook api is rather thin on this subject. All i want is something like this:

```
 FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET');
 $session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
 $access_token = getMagicAccessTokenFromSomewhere;
 $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/PAGE_ID/events', ['access_token' =>      $access_token]);
 $response = $request->execute();
 $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

But i don't know how to get the correct access_token. I cannot use the one i can retrieve using the /me/accounts because it expires in 60 minutes.

Please help... this is bugging me because i thought it would be much easier...

Comment: Store the page access token and use that

Comment: Personally, I think `getMagicAccessTokenFromSomewhere()` should be a real function.

Comment: @WizKid I can't because it is a short lived token that expires after 60 minutes.

Comment: @WizKid The access token from /me/accounts for that page: 1414530000 (in about an hour) (i read that older apps will get long live access_token, newer not...)

Comment: I was able to create a "long" (2 month) live token from the short live token using the following request: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=<APP_ID>&client_secret=<APP_SECRET>&fb_exchange_token=<SHORT_LIVED_TOKEN>

Comment: The page access tokens should always be long. If it stops working after 60 minutes you should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs